# Una pregunta no se abre en mi navegador

Tags: bug, navegador-web

Me pasa algo muy curioso con una pregunta en específico, cuando intento abrirla no puedo, me sale este error en pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es la primera vez que pasa esto.  ¿Será porque tiene la palabra `spam`en la URL, o qué será? ¿Es un problema mío o pasa a alguno de ustedes también?

[Este es el enlace de la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/222342/eliminar-publicidad-y-spam-de-wordpress-ayuda) y no es que haya sido borrada, se ve en la lista de preguntas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: asumo que es solo tuyo, por que yo desde windows 10, con google chrome actualizado puedo leer la pregunta sin problemas

Comment: @shadow ¿me podrías pasar por aquí la URL con sólo números que se obtiene desde `compartir`, debajo de la pregunta? Sospecho que se bloquea porque tiene la palabra `spam` en la URL. ¿!¡?

Comment: claro mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/222342/75901

Comment: Raro, rarísimo @shadow, tampoco se abre.

Comment: @shadow es a causa de `AdGuard`, lo pausé y ahora sí se abre. `AdGuard` me bloquea esa pregunta en específico...

Comment: vaya, lo desconocía @A.Cedano; dado el contexto considero útil que respondieras a tu propia pregunta por que a mas de un usuario lo podría resultar útil

Comment: en chrome si se ve quiza deberia actualizar tu navegador a la ultima version

Answer (score 4):

He podido acceder a la URL de esa pregunta.

El bloqueo venía de `AdGuard`, un complemento que tengo instalado en mi navegador, creo que la bloqueaba porque tenía la palabra `spam` en la URL y porque además en la pregunta se menciona mucho esa palabra, por ejemplo:

> El problema surgió cuando el anterior ingeniero que estaba intentó
>   hacer una migración usando yo no se pendejeadas y la plantilla al
>   parecer se infecto.
>
> Sale publicidad en todos lados, spam spam y mas spam.

Al poner `AdGuard` en pausa, he podido acceder a la pregunta.

Comment: La pregunta que me viene a la cabeza tras ver esta respuesta con _spam_ unas  cuantas veces es: ¿podrás acceder a esta pregunta con AdGuard activado? ;-)

Comment: @fedorqui a esta pregunta en Meta sí puedo acceder con AdGuard activado. Creo que para el bloque es determinante que la palabra *spam* forme parte de la URL, al menos es lo que intuyo.

Comment: Aunque el *spam* auténtico no suele llevar la palabra *spam*, no parece un buen criterio de bloqueo.